How to open dev tools with firefox selenium
I want to take advantage of the screenshot function from firefox dev tools. In order to execute the screenshot function in firefox devtools, in need to open the dev tools. I thought the easiest way to do thatm would be pushing the keys: command + shift + i. I created this example program that visits google.com and opens the dev tools. Unfortunately the dev tools aren't getting opened.
Example Code:
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys

def main():
    driver = webdriver.Firefox()
    driver.get("https://www.google.com")
    body_element = driver.find_element(By.CSS_SELECTOR, "body")
    body_element.send_keys(Keys.CONTROL + Keys.SHIFT + 'i')

if __name__=="__main__":
    main()

As above described there is no dev tools being opened.

What's the context here, why not just use Selenium to take the screenshot?

Doing higher resolution screenshots.

I don't think you can control the dev tools in selenium, as there are no obvious selectors with which you can specify what to do in that area.
To change the devicePixelRatio in a Firefox, you can use the layout.css.devPixelsPerPx preference:
from selenium import webdriver
profile = webdriver.FirefoxProfile()
profile.set_preference('layout.css.devPixelsPerPx', 2)
driver = webdriver.Firefox(firefox_profile=profile)


I want to make screenshots and change the dot point ratio, to make higher resolution screenshots.

Ok, I edited my answer accordingly
